# django DetailView display wrong information for User

Tags: django, django-templates, django-users, detailview

I created a superuser with syncdb but when i use `{{ object.email }}` in my detail view, I get "True" instead of the email value.

But when i use the shell the correct value is displayed.

In my view:

```
  class UserDetail(DetailView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'myapp/user/detail.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(UserDetail, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()

        if request.user.is_superuser or request.user.pk == self.object.pk:
            return super(UserDetail, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise PermissionDenied

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('cleb:user-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.object.id})
```

In my template:

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>{% trans 'Username' %}</dt><dd>{{ object.username }}</dd>
    <dt>{% trans 'First name' %}</dt><dd>{{ object.first_name }}</dd>
    <dt>{% trans 'Last name' %}</dt><dd>{{ object.last_name }}</dd>
    <dt>{% trans 'Email address' %}</dt><dd>{{ object.email }}</dd>
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
    <dt>{% trans 'Is Superuser' %}</dt><dd>{{ object.is_superuser }}</dd>
    <dt>{% trans 'Is Active' %}</dt><dd>{{ object.is_active }}</dd>
    {% endif %}
</dl>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Post your view code or the way you are using the `DetailView`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
return super(UserDetail, self).get(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

I would use:

```
 return render(request, self.template_name, {
        'object': self.object,
 })
```

I see no need to call super, there the object might be lost. What shows {{ object.username }}?